# split string into array by delemiter (Arduino)

Tags: split, arduino

i'm trying to split a string into a char array by a ";".

so something like this:

```
String a = "banana;apple;orange";
char *fruits = a.split(";");
```

What do I need to do for acheiving that?

Comment: Is this for Java or C?

Comment: @CConard96 Maybe neither...

Comment: Too many language tags -- I feel obliged to vote to close it for being too broad.

Comment: [this question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string) might help

Comment: @LoganKulinski: 1) There is no language C/C++, but the two **different languages C and C++. 2) Arduino is definitively not C, 3) nor is it exactly C++.

Answer (score 0):

We can split a string in C with [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) with a specfic delimiter ("`;`"). `strtok()` consumes the string so we must make a copy. if the original string is required elsewhere, and use the copy of the string instead of the original.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{

    char** tokens;
    char months[] = "banana;apple;orange";

    printf("fruits=[%s]\n\n", months);

    tokens = str_split(months, ';');

    if (tokens)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
        {
            printf("fruits=[%s]\n", *(tokens + i));
            free(*(tokens + i));
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(tokens);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
splitstr
fruits=[banana;apple;orange]

fruits=[banana]
fruits=[apple]
fruits=[orange]

Process finished with exit code 0
```